# Query a SQlite generated model database and returning matched query results?

Tags: ruby, database, sqlite, model-view-controller

Sorry for the noob question, I have some experience with RoR. For a quick background, I want to make a website the converts amino acids to their matching mRNA codon. I need a fixed, immutable 64 row database with 3 columns. Basically, what I want is the user to input a string into a text-area and break the string into 3 character string fragments "ttcttaatt..." --> (dnaCodon) [ttc][tta][att] --> that match to the database returning matched results (mrnaCodon ) [uuc] [uua] [auu].

My question right now is, I don't want this database viewable by users so it's all contained in the back end. I made my database as a model already so it's hidden. How do you query the database as a model and then pattern match?

This is the migration file

```
class CreateAaDataBases < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
   create_table :aa_data_bases do |t|
  t.string :aaFullName
  t.string :dnaCodon
  t.string :mrnaCodon

  t.timestamps
  end
 end
end
```

This is the database I that I created and migrated in the seeds.rb file

```
AaDataBases.create(aaFullName: "phenylalanine", dnaCodon:"ttt", mrnaCodon:"uuu")
AaDataBases.create(aaFullName: "phenylalanine",dnaCodon:"ttc",mrnaCodon:"uuc")
AaDataBases.create(aaFullName: "leucine", dnaCodon:"tta", mrnaCodon:"uua")
AaDataBases.create(aaFullName: "leucine", dnaCodon:"ttg", mrnaCodon:"uug")
AaDataBases.create(aaFullName: "leucine", dnaCodon:"ctt", mrnaCodon:"cuu")
AaDataBases.create(aaFullName: "leucine", dnaCodon:"ctc", mrnaCodon:"cuc")
AaDataBases.create(aaFullName: "leucine", dnaCodon:"cta", mrnaCodon:"cua")
AaDataBases.create(aaFullName: "leucine", dnaCodon:"ctg", mrnaCodon:"cug")
AaDataBases.create(aaFullName: "isoleucine", dnaCodon:"att", mrnaCodon:"auu")
AaDataBases.create(aaFullName: "isoleucine", dnaCodon:"atc", mrnaCodon:"auc")
```

There are an additional 54 more entries that continue on in this fashion.

This is my AaDataBases models file, I have not added anything yet.

```
class AaDataBases < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

This is a static page view for querying and returning a sequence, tried this after commented suggestions and left out code from the model. A simple test to see if it possible to access the db and return a matching value.

```
<% provide(:title, 'Sequence Results') %>
     <h1>Sequence Results</h1>

    <%= AaDataBases.where(dnaCodon: 'atc').each do |mrna| 
       puts mrna.aaFullName, mrna.mrnaCodon 
     end %>
```

The test outputs this so the page view. 
[AaDataBases id: 10, aaFullName: "isoleucine", dnaCodon: "atc", mrnaCodon: "auc", created_at: "2015-04-05 15:57:47", updated_at: "2015-04-05 15:57:47"]

Comment: Please post the code you have so far.

Comment: and your database structure

Comment: @Jordan as I said, I created the database as a model, but it lacks a view and controller. I want the DB to remain hidden from the user.

Comment: @peter added additional code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do exact matching using a hash like this.
The word mnra between || is the parameter to the block that follows, you can name it yourself. Here it represents the outcome of the database query, so it represents the record in an object form. The database fields become the members of the object. I advise you take a look at a tutorial about Activerecord like [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html) one from Rails itself.

```
AaDataBases.where(mrnaCodon: 'auc').each do |mrna|
  puts mnra.aaFullName, mnra.mnraCodon
end
```

or if you mean my matching a joker you could do this

```
AaDataBases.where('mnraCodon like _u_').each do |mrna|
 ..
end
```

or

```
AaDataBases.where('mnraCodon like %u%').each do |mrna|
 ..
end
```

EDIT

slicing a string in pieces is easy like this

```
string = "uuuuucttauuattguug"
p string.scan(/.{3}/)
```

gives

```
["uuu", "uuc", "tta", "uua", "ttg", "uug"]
```

Comment: Is this something I would add to the DB model file or would I create a controller for this to work?

Comment: normally not in the model, but otherwise you can use it where you want

Comment: sorry can you be more specific on what file to add this to? Also what exactly is |mrna|? In other words how come it isn't mrnaCodon to match the column name?

Comment: for where to place your code, i foudn this good article http://codefol.io/posts/Where-Do-I-Put-My-Code, i'll add some other stuff to the response

Comment: I ended up embedding the ruby code you provided to me in an HTML file just to test if it accesses the db, and it does! I decided to take a step back and figure out how search forms work since I still need to enter a  string block in and break it into 3char groups. But otherwise the code you provided works with accessing the database and returning a query. Much thanks